# jsTree - Get the selected node on loaded.jstree event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

How can I get the selected node on the loaded.jstree event?

what should I do in the event handler:

```
    $('#Tree').bind('loaded.jstree', function(event, data){//TODO: How to get the selected node here?}).jstree();
```

By the way, I found out that the event data arg object contains a function called get_selected() but couldn't get anything from it.

My purpose is to redirect the client to the current selected node (by 'url' attribute).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want to use the 'select_node.jstree' event to do it ?

Comment: Hi, do you have any reference or code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems according to the documentation of the demo here :

http://www.jstree.com/demo

you can do :

```
.one("reselect.jstree", function (event, data) { });
```

or

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {  
                // `data.rslt.obj` is the jquery extended node that was clicked 
                alert(data.rslt.obj.attr("id")); 
            })
```

Read carefully the documentation as :

> one is used, this is because if `refresh` is called those events are
>   triggered

```
// 1) if using the UI plugin bind to select_node
        .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
            // `data.rslt.obj` is the jquery extended node that was clicked
            alert(data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));
        })
        // 2) if not using the UI plugin - the Anchor tags work as expected
        //    so if the anchor has a HREF attirbute - the page will be changed
        //    you can actually prevent the default, etc (normal jquery usage)
        .delegate("a", "click", function (event, data) { event.preventDefault(); })
```

For the last event `delegate`, instead of writing `event.preventDefault();`, you can make your redirection correctly if you're not using the UI plugin, and write : `window.location = $(this).attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

you can select current node by :

```
$('#' + data.node.id)
```

Code becomes:

```
$('#Tree').bind('loaded.jstree', function(event, data){
console.log($('#' + data.node.id)); //This is current node, see on console
}).jstree();
```